# Print formatting array values in loop?

Tags: java

I'm learning java on my own through a book and it has a diagram I should replicate through finding array values and looping to to display from a text file. I have all the fields printing just fine but I can't seem to separate them?

[image]

I have an idea of what too do but it's just not doing what I want..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = null;
    File empFile = new File("employeesSalesRep.txt");
    String[][] empArray = new String[9][6];

    try {
        input = new Scanner(empFile);
        for (int outer = 0; input.hasNext() == true; ++outer) {
            for (int inner = 0; inner < empArray[outer].length; ++inner) {
                empArray[outer][inner] = input.next();
            }

            if (empArray[0][4].equals("22")) {

            }


        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find file.  File must be in your PROJECT folder!");
        System.out.println("System out print: " + e.getMessage());
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    finally {
        input.close();
    }

    System.out.printf("%-13s", "Emp #");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "Last Name");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "First Name");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "MI");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "Sales Rep");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "Commision");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "---------");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "---------");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "-----------");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "---------");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "----------");
    System.out.printf("%-13s", "-----------");
    System.out.println();

    for (int x = 0; x < empArray.length; ++x) {

        if (empArray[x][0] == null)
            break;

        for (int i = 0; i < empArray[x].length; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("%-13s", empArray[x][i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I don't need a direct answer. Just some direction. Give me a piece to base my code off of and I'll do the rest. I really want to learn this.

(Also any help in finding how to accumulate the totals would be great!)

Thanks.

**Edit:** 
I figured out the formatting part. But now I'm having trouble accumulating the values...

[image]

Comment: What does your current output look like?

Comment: check edit. Figured out the formatting

Comment: If the formatting is exactly the same, why not just scan the whole line and print the the system that line if it does not start with `Emp #`. That's the easiest way to do it. No need for arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just print line by line instead of storing in arrays and get the total by splitting and using the last index to add up;

```
double total = 0;

while (input.hasNextLine()){
    String line = input.nextLine();

    if ("".equals(line)){
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
        total += Double.parseDouble(split[5].trim());  // last index
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    System.out.println("-- Total for ALL SALES " + total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable to track the last value of sales rep.  When it changes (i.e. between 22 and 33) you would print your additional lines to separate the table.  You can also add a variable for total, and reset it to zero when you change the last value of sales rep.

Comment: And in order to avoid code duplication, initialize that variable to zero. That way the headings will be printed also during the first iteration. In this way you can avoid duplicating the code that prints the headings.